# Canvas is still White after brush is loaded correctly

Tags: c#, image, canvas

I have a program, where i use the Canon EDSDK. I make 40 Pictures in a Loop ( always with waiting 3 Sek. after each Photo).
Now my Problem is: After the 10th or 11th Picture my Canvas dont show the Picture it gets white. After 2 or 3 Pictures it show an Image again and then gets white for 1 or 2 pictures again....
When i look into the Debugger the Canvas.Background = MyPicture so there is not the Problem the value is correct.

Here some Code (The Event is MainCamera Download Ready) so if my Camera has something to Download it takes the picture into the CANVAS after downloading (the download Event  i made in another Class so dont wonder ^^)

```
public void MainCamera_DownloadReady(Camera sender, DownloadInfo Info)
    {
        try
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1100);
                    brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri($@"C:\Fotos\Papierkorb\TMP\{data.timeStamp}\Animation\{mc.artikelnummer.Split('_')[0]}_00_{(mc.animationsNummer - 1).ToString("00")}.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
                    LVCanvas.Background = brush;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //LoadPicsInListView();
                    sentry.BugRepport(ex.ToString(), ex);
                }
            });

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                File.Copy($@"C:\Fotos\Papierkorb\TMP\{data.timeStamp}\Animation\{mc.artikelnummer.Split('_')[0]}_00_{(mc.animationsNummer - 1).ToString("00")}.jpg", $@"C:\Fotos\{mc.artikelnummer}\{mc.artikelnummer.Split('_')[0]}\{mc.artikelnummer.Split('_')[0]}_00_{(mc.animationsNummer - 1).ToString("00")}.jpg");
                LoadPicsInListView();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            sentry.BugRepport(ex.ToString(), ex);
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Canvas Height="560" Width="840" x:Name="LVCanvas" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,0,0,0" >
```